# Existence of unique solution in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I believe it is true that if $G$ is a group and $a, b \in G$, then $a  x = b$ has a unique solution for all $ a,b \in G$. But does it hold if a third element is added, so if $a, b, c \in G$ then $a x b =c$ has a unique solution for all $a,b,c \in G$? I feel like this should be true, but couldn't $b=c$ and thus make this statement not true?

Comment: $x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}$

Comment: .Why would there be a problem if $b=c$?

Comment: If you need, put $x*b=y$ to get $a*y=c$ with a unique solution $y=d$. Then you have $x*b=d$ with  unique solution for $x$. This is just using the existence of a unique inverse for any element of a group, plus the associative law.

Answer (score 2):

Just put $x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}$ and for any element  $g\in G$, $g^{-1}$ is unique.